# HTML template - fill specific data

Tags: javascript, html

Hi guys I need to make a template html file and change specific data in it.
I've been searching how to do so and all I found was this:

```
    <div w3-include-html="tmp1.html"></div> 
<script>
function includeHTML() {
var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
/*loop through a collection of all HTML elements:*/
z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
elmnt = z[i];
/*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
if (file) {
  /*make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name:*/
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
      if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
      if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
      /*remove the attribute, and call this function once more:*/
      elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
      includeHTML();
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
  xhttp.send();
  /*exit the function:*/
  return;
}
```

}
}

But this code just copy tmp1.html and I am unable to change specific data of the file without changing the file.
Does it possible to do so?
Sorry if it's have been asked before...

Comment: Load template into a hidden `div` and use JS to change its attributes and properties. Then unhide it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a simple include system and not a template system.

Use a proper template system instead. [There are *many* for JavaScript](https://garann.github.io/template-chooser/) including [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) which would let you do something like:

```
var html = nunjucks.render('tmp1.html', { foo: 'bar' });
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
```

with a template like:

```
<div>My data is: {{foo}}</div>
```

Comment: so I need to install Nunjucks?